# Response doesn't give any output to download PDF

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf

I have field nammed RPTHtml in .aspx pahe without runat="server"

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="RPTHtml"  />
```

And add this code in javascript and call pagemethod of this page

```
document.getElementById('RPTHtml').setValue =window.encodeURI
(document.getElementById(eval(result)[0].columnLineConfig.divToRender).innerHTML);
PageMethods.getHTMLToPdf(eval(result)[0].columnLineConfig.divToRender, srcurl);
```

Now,in my page method

```
<WebMethod()> _
     <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()> _
     Public Shared Function getHTMLToPdf(ByVal div As String, ByVal InnerHTMl As String) As Boolean

    Dim pdfDocument As PdfDocument.Document = Nothing
    Dim pdfConverter As PdfConverter = New PdfConverter()
    Dim pdfBytes As Byte() = Nothing

    Dim strHtml As String = ""
    Dim htmlreport As String = ""
    Dim ReportFileName As String = ""
    Dim Response_1 As HttpResponse = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response


    If InnerHTMl.ToString() = "" Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    htmlreport = InnerHTMl.ToString()



    htmlreport = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(htmlreport)

    Response_1.Clear()
    Response_1.Buffer = True
    Response_1.ClearContent()
    Response_1.ClearHeaders()

    ReportFileName = GetReportName() + ".pdf"

    pdfConverter = New Winnovative.WnvHtmlConvert.PdfConverter()

    pdfConverter.AvoidImageBreak = True
    pdfConverter.AvoidTextBreak = True
    pdfConverter.TruncateOutOfBoundsText = True
    pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "LicenseKey"
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.PdfPageSize = PdfPageSize.A4
    pdfConverter.PdfDocumentOptions.StretchToFit = True

    pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(htmlreport)

    Response_1.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/pdf")
    Response_1.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + ReportFileName)

    Response_1.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes)
    Response_1.Flush()
    Response_1.End()        
End Function
```

It doesn't give any output,just run successfully, but prompt for download pdf is not occurring.

Something i missed? or it can't achieve by pagemethod.
thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Try "Content-type", "application/force-download" as your cotnent type.

Comment: you mean i have to add new header Response_1.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/pdf").Response_1.AddHeader("Content-type", "application//force-download")

Comment: no, just replace your header value.

Comment: it also doesn't work....!

Comment: Since you are calling this through javascript, try with implementing the same method on as seperate webpage in page load instead of as a 'web method', and call the web page in your link.

Comment: yes,you are right.but problem is. i need to pass both argument to the other page.and innerHTMl has long string so i can't use query string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30491/discussion-between-jeegnesh-and-furqan)

Comment: And when i store this innerHTML in hidden filed.that time i don't know to access that value back from the hiddenfield. I tried  "hiddenfield.value.ToString()"....but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Give a link in you asp.net page like

```
      <a href="javascript:ExportReport();">Export To Excel</a>
```

in javascript(I used jquery to do the same), create an HTML form dynamically and submit it, `Export.aspx` is the page that shall generate the pdf

```
   function ExportReport() {                            
                        var frmT = $([
                            '<form id="frmExport" method="post" action="Export.aspx" target="_blank" style="display:none;">',
                                '<input type="hidden" name="pdfContents" id="tableContents" />',                                    
                            '</form>'

                        ].join('')).appendTo('body')[0]
                        var hdnTbl = $("#pdfContents", frmT);
                        hdnTbl.val( divRep.html() ); //  divRep.html() is the inner html you want to convert to PDF

                        frmT.submit();

                    }
```

Since you are submitting HTML in your hidden field you need to enable `ValidateRequest` attribute in your `Export.aspx` page

```
        ValidateRequest="false"
```

additionally you need to enable maxrequestlength in web.config like following,

```
        <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="1024" />  <!-- 1024 kb  -->
```

before `</system.web>` closing tag. If you are using .net 2.0 , you can omit the `requestValidationMode="2.0"` attribute. you can use the same `getHTMLToPdf` method code in your export.aspx page load method.
Hope this shall help.

Comment: I have the same problem. Jeegnesh, did last answer help you?

Comment: i never tried that, but i ended up implanting Whole  getHTMLToPdf method on new page, to get better response.